# Are there any UNIX environment variables longer than four characters?

Tags: unix

I know there is $USER, $HOME, $PATH, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are plenty: DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS, XAUTHORITY, GDM_LANG, etc. You can view all your environment variables with the `env` command - type it in inside a terminal.

As far as I know, there's no limitations on environment variables, they can be of any length, and anything can create them and add them to the environment (using `export`, as you may have seen). Conceptually, environment variables act as "global variables" that are shared among all programs running in a terminal.

Answer (score 7):

Err... lots?

```
$ env | cut -d = -f 1 | sort | uniq 
_
COLORFGBG
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
DESKTOP_SESSION
DISPLAY
DM_CONTROL
EDITOR
GPG_AGENT_INFO
GS_LIB
GTK2_RC_FILES
GTK_RC_FILES
HISTCONTROL
HOME
KDE_FULL_SESSION
KDE_MULTIHEAD
KDE_SESSION_UID
KDE_SESSION_VERSION
KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE
KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION
LANG
LANGUAGE
LESSCLOSE
LESSOPEN
LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH
LOGNAME
LS_COLORS
OLDPWD
PATH
PROFILEHOME
PWD
QT_PLUGIN_PATH
SESSION_MANAGER
SHELL
SHLVL
SSH_AGENT_PID
SSH_AUTH_SOCK
TERM
USER
WINDOWID
WINDOWPATH
XCURSOR_THEME
XDG_DATA_DIRS
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE
XDM_MANAGED
```

Comment: There's no need for the uniq(ue) because you can't have 2 the same.

Comment: Yeah, fair point. I tend to uniq after sorting to keep down the noise in a general text pipeline, but it is unnecessary in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, `$SHELL` is one of them that I know of.

Edit: see [this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/general/linux-unix-list-common-environment-variables.php) for more of them.

Answer (score 1):

How about `$DISPLAY` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Every system is configured differently so rather than listing them all here, just enter the following command to list them all on your own system:

```
set | sed 's/=.*//' | grep -v "^[A-Z_]\{4\}$"
```

I'd use `set` instead of `env` as it has greater scope. Most system environment variables are in upper case so to add that restriction add an extra grep to the pipe line.

```
set | sed 's/=.*//' | grep "[A-Z_]" | grep -v "^[A-Z_]\{4\}$"
```

Answer (score 1):

env | cut -d = -f 1 | grep -E "([A-Z_]{4,})"

Use this command

Answer (score 0):

`$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `$LD_PRELOAD` both exist for linking.

Answer (score 0):

User defined environment variables don't have to four characters long (ex. CLASSPATH)